# jQuery One page nav not responding properly

Tags: jquery, navigation, nav

I’m having an issue with the following jQuery script.
I’m using “Trevor Davis – One page nav (https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav)” for my portfolio, but it has one slight problem for me.
When scrolling down the menu automatically changes the state of the menu (current navigation class or nothing), I love this but when I scroll down and the next section comes to the half of my screen it already changes it the navigation class.

For example:

[HOME – ABOUT ME – PORTFOLIO – CONTACT]

When I’m currently at the “ABOUT ME” page (“ABOUT ME” has the navigation class of “current” atm) and I’m scrolling down, and the portfolio page is taking up 50% of my screen it changes the portfolio navigation class already to current instead of waiting until it reaches the top.

I’d like it to change when it only reaches the top of my navigation.

Ps: you can see the problem I’m explaining on his demo page: http://trevordavis.net/play/jquery-one-page-nav/

Comment: It would help if we could see an actual example of the problem.  Or it would probably be hard to answer your question.  Do you have a link to your webpage or something?

Comment: @hamobi he has example in his question... http://trevordavis.net/play/jquery-one-page-nav/

Comment: this is the official site's example i think.  not his own website

Comment: @hamobi , its indeed the example but it has the same problem.
if you scroll down there you will see when section 3 hits the middle of the page that it will automaticaly change the navigation class to section 3 current. i want it to change the navigation class when it section 3 is at the top of the page . i hope you know what I mean, i'l upload a picture later on when i'm at home